# django: Pass additional data to context in FormView

Tags: django

I’m new to this forum and this is my first question, so please be kind Before I state my question, here is the code to the regarding model, form, view and template

```
class Medium(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    dateiname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dateipfad = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    MEDIEN_TYP = (
        ('f', 'Foto'),
        ('v', 'Video'),
        ('d', 'Dokument'),
    )

    typ = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, choices=MEDIEN_TYP, blank=True, default='Foto')

    URHEBER_NAME = (
        ('a', 'Person A'),
        ('b', 'Person B'),
    )

    urheber = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, choices=URHEBER_NAME, blank=True, default='Person A')

    datum_erstellung = models.DateField(
        null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Erstelldatum')
    personen = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Person(en)')
    ort = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    inhalt = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Inhalt/Anlass')
    kommentar = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    rating = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=3, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('medium-detail-view', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.dateiname
```

```
class AbfrageForm(forms.Form):

    medien_typen = (
        ("f", "Foto"),
        ("v", "Video"),
        ("d", "Dokument"),
    )

    medien_typ = forms.ChoiceField(choices=medien_typen)

    personen = (
        ("Person X", "13: Person X"),
        ("Person Y", "14: Person Y"),
        ("Person Z", "14: Person Z"),
    )
    vorname = forms.ChoiceField(choices=personen)

    orte = (
        ("Place A", "Place A"),
        ("Place B", "Place B"),
    )
    ort = forms.ChoiceField(choices=orte)
```

```
class AbfrageView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'abfrage.html'
    form_class = AbfrageForm
    success_url = '.'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AbfrageView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        #context['auswahl'] = self.auswahl
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):

        typ = form.cleaned_data['medien_typ']
        vorname = form.cleaned_data['vorname']
        ort = form.cleaned_data['ort']

        auswahl = Medium.objects.all().filter(
            typ__contains=typ, personen__contains=vorname, ort__contains=ort).values('dateiname', 'dateipfad', 'typ', 'urheber',
                                                                                     'datum_erstellung', 'personen', 'ort', 'inhalt', 'kommentar')

        return super(AbfrageView, self).form_valid(form)
```

```
<body>
    {% block content %}
    
    <form action="" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{form}}
      <input type="submit" value="Absenden" />
    </form>
    
    {% for item in context %}
      <ul>
        <li>{{item.dateiname}}</li>
        <li>{{item.dateipfad}}</li>
      </ul>
  
    {% endfor %}

    {% endblock %}
  </body>
```

The question is: How can I add the additional content, queried from the Medien-model in the AbfrageView to the context and render it in the template? The query is working fine, maybe I don’t see the elephant in the room!?

Thanks in advance,
TheHotch

Comment: It can be a bit complicated to filter things dynamically. Try using this library that helps you do it [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/). To solve your problem without any external libraries instead of calling the super classes form_valid method you should render a template in your form_valid method.

Comment: I do not fully agree. If you just want to filter, it is easy to do it using a `ListView` with a `FormMixin` - I'm convinced creating it "by hand" will help to understand the core of django better than using an add-in for every task.

Answer (score 0):

There is some unneeded stuff in your code. To answer your initial question:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    # no "all()" before ".filter()"
    auswahl = Medium.objects.filter(typ__contains='whatever')
    context['auswahl'] = auswahl
    return context
```

You may add your context whatever you need in the get_context_data - as you did. (You may leave the `super()` empty - repetition of the class and `self` is redundant.)

Bear in mind the a variable defined in one funcion (`def`) is unknown in another.

Allow me to add some comments to your other code:

```
class Medium(models.Model):
    # not needed as django keeps track themself to have an id
    # id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    dateiname = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    MEDIEN_TYP = (
        ('f', 'Foto'),
        # ...
    )

    typ = models.CharField(
        # if you choose a default, then it must be from the first tuple-element
        # the length of your fiel may be as short as your choice (plus reserver for later usage)
        max_length=2, choices=MEDIEN_TYP, blank=True, default='f')
    
    # ...
 
    urheber = models.CharField(
        # do not use German terms in your variable names...
        # as above, the default:
        max_length=20, choices=URHEBER_NAME, blank=True, default='a')
```

Your form class is redundant. It is enough to use the ModelForm

```
class AbfrageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Medium
        fields = '__all__'
```

What do you want to filter here and why do you provide every field?

```
auswahl = Medium.objects.all().filter(
          typ__contains=typ, personen__contains=vorname, ort__contains=ort)
          .values('dateiname', 'dateipfad', 'typ', 'urheber','datum_erstellung', 
           'personen', 'ort', 'inhalt', 'kommentar')
```

The `.value` part is sensless as you have the Medium object in the variable with all fields anyway.

Finally in your template, there is no need to loop over some whatever context as the form was rendered in the view already. All choices are taken from the model without coding them. "Weniger ist mehr!" ;-)

Your `form_valid()` is doing nothing - just comment it out for now. This is run through after you have filled in your form and posting it (press "Absenden" in your example). If you need to check what has been entered, you'll do that in `form_valid()`.

I hope I could help a little.

Comment: I think the OP is trying to make a view to search / filter, you should change your answer to reflect that.

Comment: This would be an entirely different approach using a `ListView` with a `FormMixin`. The ListView to display the content and the form to use it for filtering. Then you will use the `form.cleaned_data` to filter the object before returning it...